# Cast to a pointer to a Cython extension class

Tags: python, cython

I'm new to Cython so bear with me. I'm trying to cast some data to a pointer to an extension class. The class is essentially a glorified struct. It is declared in my .pxd file as:

```
cdef class Field:

    cdef:
        np.float64_t u                   # x velocity
        np.float64_t v                   # y velocity
        np.float64_t w                   # z velocity

    cdef update(self)
```

And of course this is implemented in a .pyx file. In my driver code, I have a 4-dimensional array of `np.float64_t`'s. The first three dimensions represent x, y, and z. The fourth dimension is supposed to represent these three values `u, v, w`. I allocate the grid in a pure Python driver program which then passes the grid to a Cython file. In the Cython file, I cast:

```
curr_grid_element = (<Field *> &grid[xx, yy, zz, 0])
curr_grid_element.update()
```

But when I do so, I get the error: `Pointer base type cannot be a Python object`.

Which has me rather confused, as I thought `Field` was pure C.

Comment: `Field` is a C struct which contains the fields u,v,w you specied, but it also contains the standard Python reference counting mechanism. Therefore you can't really reinterpret a `grid` array as a `Field` because it doesn't contain the same reference counting fields.

Answer (score 4):

Cython [extension types](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html) do not translate into c structures, they translate to python built in types. At a high level this means `Field` is a python class which happens to be implemented in C, like `list` or `ndarray` for example. At a lower level, cython does use c structures to implement extension types but these structures have fields you are not accounting for. Namely a field for tracking its type and anther for reference counting (maybe some others too).

I think what you want is struct, not an extension type. Try this:

```
cdef struct Field:
    np.float64_t u                   # x velocity
    np.float64_t v                   # y velocity
    np.float64_t w                   # z velocity
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After some thought yesterday, I came to the same conclusion. But now when I pass a Field * (i.e. my grid) to a function defined using cdef in a .pyx file, I get the error "Could not cast Field * to Python Object". Why would it be casting a pointer to a Field to an object when the function accepts a Field *? I can post code later, on mobile right now.